# window.print() only print half of the content and only 1 page

Tags: css

When using `window.print()` my content get's limited only to 1 page.

Im having problem to upload my code here, cause im getting wrong formatting all the time, so here is the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctqj2f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `.modal { position: fixed }` is to blame

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9pdvv

Comment: actually - position absulte fixed it, when it was position fixed my modal didnt shop up somehow..